# GameObject position changing in world space after removed from parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game with Unity, and I am making an enemy drop his weapon. The Weapon's vector (in local space) is (0, 0, 1.71), and I am using the following function:

```
void SetGunDrop()
{
    gun.SetParent (null);
    gun.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = false;
    Rigidbody rb = gun.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

However, right after detaching from the parent, the weapon translates to (0, 0, 1.71) in *world position*, translates away from the enemies body to the center of the map.

Is there a way to avoid this, and make the gun fall straight from its position to the ground?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting the gun transform's parent equal to null or to the transform of the world space, then add the X/Y/Z transform value of the GameObject dropping the gun to the transform's X/Y/Z.

```
void SetGunDrop() {
   var parentT = gun.parent.transform;
   gun.SetParent (null);
   gun.position += new Vector(parentT.x, parentT.y, parentT.z); 
   gun.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = false;
   Rigidbody rb = gun.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
   rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

If you want some more information on Transform.SetParent(), check out Unity's documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html). For some more information on moving Unity Transforms around, here's a [post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/set-value-on-gameobject-transform-position-x-with-c.66768/) about it. Good luck!

**EDIT:** Updated to reflect gun variable being a transform GameObject :)

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to add that! The _gun_ variable is a transform, and I will also try what you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this is to store the world position of the gun before dropping it.

```
void SetGunDrop()
{
    Vector3 tempPosition = gun.position;
    gun.SetParent (null);
    gun.position = tempPosition;

    gun.GetComponent<Animator> ().enabled = false;
    Rigidbody rb = gun.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.isKinematic = false;
}
```

This should work for you, good luck!

Comment: The problem is that that also did not work. The gun just stayed in the same position, even after I set its position with Translate() and with the way that you proposed. However, I found an alternative that is a lot cleaner and optimized, but thanks for helping anyway!